# Senseless revision?

Tags: discussion, editing, revisions

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577286/why-is-t-canonical-parameter-appended-to-searches-made-on-duckduckgo-from-fire) question was edited but I do not understand why. [This](https://askubuntu.com/posts/577286/revisions) shows the revisions. I found revision 2, the removal of the `14.04` tag, to be rather subjective but acceptable. However, revision 3 doesn't make sense to me.

The original title was more adequate and I liked the structure of the question with the bullet points. The problem was clearly stated and a question was asked. There was even a nice picture illustrating the issue.

From [when should I edit posts](https://askubuntu.com/help/editing):

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than
>   you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (**without changing that meaning**) [emphasis added]
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

I do like the shadow added to the image. As for the rest, is this a case of gratuitous editing?

(*Note: not a bashing attempt.*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it was completely without reason.

- The title makes more pertinent; this *is* about DDG in Firefox, nothing else.
- There was no good reason for separating two paragraphs with bullets; they're not a list.
- The question about *why* there's a `t=...` querystring item needed bringing into the main question rather than leaving as a side-bar at the end (you might not want want to remove it if it were important).
- As you mention, the shadow removes ambiguity between the page (which is a white background) and the DDG element which is also mostly white.

You could argue whether or not fixing these things makes a measurable improvement worthy of the time that went into them but Aditya isn't getting anything for performing the edit. I don't think it's unfair to assume that they only have the best interest of you and the question in mind.

Comment: The title is not more pertinent. I wanted to know how to remove it, the why was a secondary question (which is why it was in braces at the bottom of the question). The current title emphasizes the *why* instead of the **how** and that was not the main issue I was attempting to solve. I would have accepted an answer without the why but not without the how. I'd suspect others are also more interested in knowing how to get rid of the `t=canonical` than on why it is there, not that I have made a survey on public opinion about it.

Comment: Call me old fashioned but why would you want to remove something if you don't know what it is our does?

Comment: "*Call me old fashioned but why would you want to remove something if you don't know what it is our does?*" -- I inferred from the looks of it that it was used to track me and that's enough for me to want to remove it, but I wanted to understand why. In other words, why is Canonical including tracking strings in my searches without **explicitly** asking me about it first. It reminds me of the so-called *online search results* that were sending my data to Amazon. I like to believe Ubuntu still puts users' privacy ahead of `$$$`.

Comment: Either which way (given "canonical" is an English word that could determine a type of search), identifying should be a core part of a good question and answer. I'm not saying asking how to remove it (if bad) is a good idea. My "more pertinent" was really about adding Firefox and DDG to the title because it isn't in all browsers on all search engines.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Although Firefox+DDG are mentioned in the body I agree they should have also been included in the title.